# How do you make a multiplication sign in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typesetting, resource-recommendations, symbols, character

It looks like an "x" but not quite. I am using Adobe Illustrator 2023 on a Mac, if that matters.

Comment: You mean literally construct one from scratch, as opposed to just find one in unicode? Unicode is `U+2716` `U+FE0F` ✖️[Taken from the horribly-named but very useful 'Emoji & Symbols' panel.]

Comment: +1 @Tetsujin: do you need to use both commands?

Comment: either/or, decimal/hex

Comment: @Tetsujin ×[`U+00D7`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00D7) is the standard multiplication sign. ️️✖`U+FE0F` is "Heavy Multiplication" and is likely to look odd in most fonts if it's even present. I couldn't enter it in the comment box, and when I pasted it from the search bar where I could, it was smaller and heavier than the one in your comment (✖✖️).  These less common symbols must provoke some strange substitutions

Comment: A multiplication/cross product sign differs from the letter X (or x) in that whatever the font, even it should have right angles and equal length arms, even in italics (mathematical typesetting commonly uses italics for variables; symbols are always upright).  It should also be centred rather than sitting on the baseline, but this isn't strictly observed.

Comment: ...Even stranger, I get different output for `U+2716` and `U+FE0F` testing in Firefox's search box, though actually searching on it gives the same result - but of course FE0F != 2716; FE0F is "Variation Selector" - a non-spacing mark

Comment: Interesting - my system prompts that one first, the 00D7 second, then several more of more complex structure - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ap0C6.png

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### ×

If you don't know how to use Glyphs panel, the quicker way is to google *"multiplication sign*" and you will get this character "×".

Copy paste this character "×" into your document and, ***assuming*** your font includes this character (some fonts can have a limited math symbols set), then you should be good to go.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_sign

Comment: I know the question is for Mac, but for posterity, on Windows with a numpad, hold down alt key, type 0215 on numpad and then release alt. Should work system-wide. It is CP1252, but I think laps with Unicode in this case. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code)

Answer (score 5):

I cheat....

Make a `+` in practically *any* font. Then using the **Character Panel** rotate it 45°

[image]

Some typefaces work better than others. This often aids in the `x` remaining visually consistent with any surrounding typeface.

Afterwards you can easily set up a **Character Style** to repeat it.

Comment: Pumpkin eater! :D

Comment: ....seeds and .. pie.. yup `:)`

Comment: Not a bad idea if the font lacks the symbol.

Answer (score 2):

Provided the symbol is included in the font you're using, all of its symbols can be found in the Glyphs palette.

1. Make sure you have a blinking text cursor by creating or editing a text with the Text tool;
2. Open the Glyphs palette through Type > Glyphs;
3. Scroll through the available glyphs in the palette and find the multiplication symbol;
4. Double-click the symbol.

This will output the symbol you chose on the position of your text cursor.

Comment: thing is the glyphs panel kindof sux, it does not allow you to search by name. So if the font is even moderately character heavy it might be hard to find. And googling is a better option. Thing is though on widows there is a builtin application that allows you to search and filter glyphs by name. And its way way more usable than adobes panel is due to this even if it sucks in all other ways. Youd think adobe could youknow allow search.

Comment: I think in InDesign they have a category selector in the Glyphs panel, so you can only display "math symbols" in a font, which would make the "×" easier to spot.